# With google maps, can you use google's own popup windows?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps

I've implemented a google map with points and stuff that uses an address that the user inputs. When you click a point, the popup bubble appears with the name and address in.

Often this name and address is a prominent location, as it's used for meetings and things, such as a university. If you google the address yourself on maps.google.co.uk then you get google's own popup bubble, which often has a photo, information, opening hours, links to directions, reviews, etc. etc.

I am wondering if there's a way to use that popup dialog instead of my own, where it is available. I can't see anything in the API to do this.

I'm using V2 as we support IE6 in a lot of our users, but I've been told recently I can upgrade to V3 should I need functionality from it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you've been told that you can upgrade to V3, I'd do so since the Maps V2 API is now deprecated. Unfortunately, the Maps V3 API removed support for FF 2, IE 6, and Safari 3

FWIW, I have an example of an `InfoWindow` (in V3) displaying an image here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kai/Unh2M/

An `InfoWindow` can contain HTML so you can fill it with whatever you want. The V2 API has a similar method, `GInfoWindow` -- there is an example of its usage here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Info_Windows

Comment: Thanks, yeah using IE6 is the reason we have kept it. I am currently putting html into my infoboxes, but it would be nice if it had the same functionality as google maps ie. http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=bristol+university&sll=53.800651,-4.064941&sspn=22.752248,67.631836&ie=UTF8&hq=bristol+university&hnear=&z=13&iwloc=C

Comment: I understand. You can create the same functionality; the HTML elements in the `GInfoWindow` can be styled and have events attached to them for effects. Simply attach the events after the `GInfoWindow` is opened and remove them before its closed.